# How to get edited text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get edited content from WYSIWYG?

Here is the documentation https://editor.froala.com/docs

```
<div id='edit1'></div>
<input type="button" onclick="save()" value="Save">
<div class="edited_content">
```

Instead of this text I want to type edited content, after by clicking `save</div>`

http://jsfiddle.net/w4EmN/179/

Comment: Have you looked for this in [documentation](https://editor.froala.com/methods#getHTML)?

Comment: @alex_kalenyuk Yes, I have looked, but didn't find the way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get edited content from WYSIWYG?

```
$('div#edit1').editable('getHTML');
```

Here is an simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/w4EmN/180/

When you click on "Save" It's will "alert" the html content.

[See more in documentation](https://editor.froala.com/methods#getHTML)

Comment: You do that `<input type="button" onclick="$('.edited_content').html($('div#edit1').editable('getHTML'))" value="Save">` Here is an another example for you: https://jsfiddle.net/w4EmN/181/